# Buddypress: Modifying BP-Default

Tags: buddypress

I have a task, *remove all modifications directly to the  buddypress plugin*, I started by replacing bp-default, with a **new fresh** downloaded copy, and the site stopped working.

**Clearly, the site was dependent on something in that dir**

So my question is:

**Is modifying the bp-default dir consider acceptable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its suggested, and is a good practice to not modify anything inside the bp-default theme. So as of your question, 'no its not considered acceptable'.
That is because a future update of buddypress will replace everything you've changed. So its better to create your own child theme and do all the editing there.